# Does Enju have precognitive abilities?

Tags: black-bullet

Cursed children are shown through the series to have many superhuman abilities: enhaced speed, force, healing, vision etc. There is an episode where Enju had "a bad feeling" and inmediately a shot by Tina Sprout is shown to almost kill Seinteshi. How did she know this? Does Enju have precognitive abilities?

Comment: Can you provide the episode and timestamp? I cannot find it with a quick glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursed Children's abilities comes from two things, firstly the Gastrea virus which grants them enhanced strength, agility and their healing ability

> Superhuman powers of healing. That was one of the benefits they had as Initiators—girls who could control the Gastrea virus under certain conditions. The extraordinary muscular strength and agility they possessed also fell into that category.
>
> *Kanzaki, Shiden. Black Bullet, Vol. 1: Those Who Would Be Gods (p. 26). Yen Press. Kindle Edition.*

Secondly from the animal factor from which they gain their other abilities

> Enju seemed to realize something and looked worriedly at Rentaro, but she finally faced forward and said, “I’ll defeat him in ten seconds!” and dashed off in a blast with the superfast acceleration that could be called a distinguishing trait of Model Rabbits.
>
> *Kanzaki, Shiden. Black Bullet, Vol. 1: Those Who Would Be Gods (p. 173). Yen Press. Kindle Edition.*
>
> Kohina kept her face down and grumbled softly to herself. “Enju, Enju, Enju… All right, I’ll remember. I am Model Mantis, Kohina Hiruko. In close combat, I am invincible.”
>
> *Kanzaki, Shiden. Black Bullet, Vol. 1: Those Who Would Be Gods (p. 90). Yen Press. Kindle Edition.*

It is never mentioned that the Gastrea virus grants precognition and as no animal has precognition it is fairly safe to assume that no Cursed Child posses this ability either. Neither Enju, nor any other Curse Child ever shows any signs of being able to perceive the future otherwise they would have been absolutely unbeatable in combat (and Enju gets beaten up fairly often). The following excerpt rather clearly shows that she did not expect the attack.

> At that moment, Rentaro glanced sharply at the glowing, slimy green strands, completely unlike a normal spider’s silk. It was the same as the stuff he had seen in the victim Sumiaki Okajima’s house. “Get down, Enju!” “Huh?” The girl couldn’t react to the quick order. Her frail body was thrown to the side, and she flew almost twenty meters, scraping the ground so violently that she left a mark.
>
> *Kanzaki, Shiden. Black Bullet, Vol. 1: Those Who Would Be Gods (p. 22). Yen Press. Kindle Edition.*

Most likely the reason Enju said this is due to a regular "gut feeling" that something bad was going to happen and nothing more.